# Table Cells: white-space nowrap until a max-width has been met, then wrap

Tags: css, html-table, width, nowrap

In the example below, I want the cells to **not wrap** until they've reached the `max-width`. This would still cause the table to overflow, which **is** the behavior I want.

```css
main {
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>One Two</th>
    <th>One Two Three</th>
    <th>Four</th>
    <th>Five</th>
    <th>Six</th>
    <th>Seven</th>
    <th>Seven Eight</th>
    <th>Seven Eight Nine</th>
    <th>Seven Eight Nine Ten</th>
  </tr>
  </table>
</main>
```

Comment: 1) which `max-width` are you talking about? `600` or `120`. 2) if `max-width` is `600`, then do you think using `nowrap` has any meaning if you're wrapping the contents just on overflow? Please explain your problem more clearly, as in the current form, it is very poorly-described and is a low-quality post.

Comment: The `th` `max-width` of `120`. I want the `th` cells to act like `nowrap` until they've hit a width of `120` at which point I want them to wrap.

Comment: Maybe I did not fully understand the problem until now, but when we remove the "white-space: nowrap" for the th-selector, I see the intended behaviour (as far as I understood it). The th-cells expand depending on the amount of text until they reached 120px width. Then the text starts wrapping and the th-width is 120px. What did I misunderstand here?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply *not possible in css* without **javascript**.
I have made a short script that checks if the width is greater than 119 and if so sets that elements style to normal wrapping as you wanted.

```
 var a = document.querySelectorAll("th");

 a.forEach((a) => {
   if(a.offsetWidth > 119) {
     a.style.whiteSpace = "normal";
   }else {
     console.log(a.offsetWidth);
   }

 });
```

[image]

---

### Full code

---

html

```
<main>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th class="t">One</th>
    <th>One Two</th>
    <th>One Two Three</th>
    <th>Four</th>
    <th>Five</th>
    <th>Six</th>
    <th>Seven</th>
    <th>Seven Eight</th>
    <th>Seven Eight Nine</th>
    <th>Seven Eight Nine Ten</th>
  </tr>
  </table>
</main>

<script type="text/javascript">

     var a = document.querySelectorAll("th");

     a.forEach((a) => {
       if(a.offsetWidth > 119) {
         a.style.whiteSpace = "normal";
       }else {
         console.log(a.offsetWidth);
       }

     });

</script>
```

css

```
main {
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe an upgrade to the CSS standard could add something like ```white-space: nowrap(max-width: 400);```

Comment: You'd have to add `width: 120px` to the style, but yeah, that is a JS solution.

Comment: @Dan is javascript not a valid solution?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use this:

add `word-wrap: break-word;` and remove `white-space: nowrap;`

#### Css:

```
main {
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  max-width: 120px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

#### Html code:

```
<main>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>One Two</th>
    <th>One Two Three</th>
    <th>Four</th>
    <th>Five</th>
    <th>Six</th>
    <th>Seven</th>
    <th>Seven Eight</th>
    <th>Seven Eight Nine</th>
    <th>Seven Eight Nine Ten</th>
  </tr>
  </table>
</main>
```

#### The result is:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just remove

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

See [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GDQQVSUZBSMB)

[image: The Result]